# robot framework element with locator not found

Tags: html, selenium, robotframework, angular4-forms

I got following error while testing my application in robot framework using RIDE editor.

> Element with locator 'xpath: //*[contains(text(), "**Applicant**")]' not found.

But my HTML page contains that **Applicant** text

when I edit that name with "**Applicant1**" the error was gone. But I cant put it as "**Applicant1**" in my application. I want **Applicant** in my HTML page.

I am using Angular4 for my application. And Applicant is from side menu it is used from Cupa menu npm library Following is code which shows how I use that applicant to display on the HTML page.

Below is **.ts** File

```
 menuItemsArray: any[] = [

    { 'title': 'Loan Application', 'link': 'loan-creation',
        'subItems': [
        { 'title': 'Create Loan Application', 'link': 'loan-creation' },
        { 'title': 'List Of Loan Applications', 'link': 'list-of-loan-application' },
        { 'title': 'Loan Application Details', 'link': 'get-loan-details-by-id' },
      ]
    },
       {
                    'title': 'Applicant', 'link': 'applicant-creation',
                        'subItems': [
                            { 'title': 'Create New Applicant', 'link': 'applicant-creation' },
                            { 'title': 'List Of Applicants', 'link': 'list-of-consumer' },
                        ]
                }
 ];
```

And below is **.html** file

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md top-navbar jh-navbar">
     <cuppa-slidemenu name="cupaBar" [menulist]="menuItemsArray" [config]="menuConfig"  (open)="onMenuOpen()" (close)="onMenuClose()" (onItemSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"></cuppa-slidemenu>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
  aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="fa fa-navicon"></span>
  </button>
```

Please help me

`Click CreateApplicant
    Click Element    xpath: //*[contains(text(), "Applicant")]`

I used above code for clicking "**Applicant**" text. But it doesn't work. With name "**Applicant**" It only works with "**Applicant1**". Also, it was work with other options like Loan Application, Create Loan Application.

Comment: Would be nice if you provide relevant HTML to the question

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that the text doesn't repeat anywhere else then you can use

```
Click CreateApplicant
    Click Element    xpath: //*[contains(., "Applicant")]
```

Comment: yes. I am sure. this text was not repeated in my code

Comment: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Comment: I may not help you on that error. Can you please update your thread with the code you have tried and the error. May be someone else can help you out

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Click CreateApplicant
    Click Element    xpath: //*[contains(text(), "applicant-creation")]
```

Comment: it will not work when you get Applicant then and only then you can click on "applicant-creation". because it is sub menu of Applicant

Comment: Did you try it? Because of this `'title': 'Applicant', 'link': 'applicant-creation'` it can work

Comment: It can not work because after clicking on applicant it will expand and only after that applicant-creation is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Click CreateApplicant
    Click Element    xpath: //"[starts-with(@text,"applicant-creation")]